# How to handle enums in hive flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am using hive to store data in local storage
I want to know how to store enum in hive in flutter.
This is my model class

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'todo.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
enum Priority {
  @HiveField(0)
  low,

  @HiveField(1)
  medium,

  @HiveField(2)
  high,
}

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Todo {
  @HiveField(0)
  String task;

  @HiveField(1, defaultValue: false)
  bool isCompleted;

  @HiveField(2)
  Priority priority;

  Todo({required this.task, required this.isCompleted, required this.priority});
}
```

The error I am encountering.

`E/flutter (13947): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Priority' in type cast E/flutter (13947): #0      TodoAdapter.read (package:todo/data/todo.g.dart:22:27)`

Comment: You can set a default value  
`Todo({required this.task, required this.isCompleted, this.priority = Priority. mediun});`